# How can you tell if an Ember view's element is in the document?

Tags: ember.js

How can you tell your Ember view's element has been inserted into the document?

My current method is to do:

```
if (this.$().length) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: this is a solution. If you want the callback that said elements has been inserted, you could override the method `didInsertElement` ( see the doc: http://goo.gl/GfvyP )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is checking the dictionary of views. If you have a view like:

```
var helloView = Em.View.create({
  elementId: 'hello'
});
```

You can do:

```
var myView = Ember.View.views.hello;

// Check if it is in the DOM
myView.get('state') === "inDOM";

// Check if it is visible
myView.get('isVisible');
```

Comment: I could be wring, but I don't think this works in the latest Ember (RC3).

Comment: Ember core team recommended to not use `.state` property.